# Search full git commit message body

Tags: git

`git log --grep=searchstring` appears to only search the first line of every commit message. How do I search the entire commit message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of `git` are you using?  With version 1.7.7.6, the `--grep` option appears to search through the entire content of commit messages.  Take for example this log:

```
$ git log
commit 7d3f6ed90467f40de32ea4e59f8fa4172735d577
Author: Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@seas.harvard.edu>
Date:   Wed May 9 14:10:12 2012 -0400

    i added a file

    this is the second line.

commit 3aaf84486d0f1eb41fb5406254f795a581ef0ce2
Author: Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@seas.harvard.edu>
Date:   Wed May 9 14:10:01 2012 -0400

    i made a change

commit eb6cd7773ff68808a9eda2e7edb8fbffcc1f6759
Author: Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@seas.harvard.edu>
Date:   Wed May 9 14:09:45 2012 -0400

    this is the first line

    this is the second line
```

If I grep for the word `second`, I get:

```
$ git log --grep=second
commit 7d3f6ed90467f40de32ea4e59f8fa4172735d577
Author: Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@seas.harvard.edu>
Date:   Wed May 9 14:10:12 2012 -0400

    i added a file

    this is the second line.

commit eb6cd7773ff68808a9eda2e7edb8fbffcc1f6759
Author: Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@seas.harvard.edu>
Date:   Wed May 9 14:09:45 2012 -0400

    this is the first line

    this is the second line
```

This is clearly matching something other than the first line.

Comment: the problem was the commit i was looking for was on a different branch. need to add `--all`